# VueJS Adding data to array for child table

Tags: vue.js

I'm having trouble pushing data to an array of data. I have 2 components, the parent component which includes the Folders child component, the data, and a button that triggers a function which is supposed to add data to the array:

```
<a-button 
   type="primary" 
   style="marginLeft: 20px"
   @click="onClickNew"
>
  + New
</a-button>
<Folders 
    :item="item_key" 
    @selected="onSelectedRow" 
    :searchField="searchData" 
    :data="dataUpdate"
/>
data() {
  return {
    data: json,
    collapsed: false,
    item_key: 1,
    searchData: '',
    folderName: '',
    visible: false,
    confirmLoading: false,
  };
},
components: {
  Folders
},
computed: {
  dataUpdate() {
     return this.data;
  }
},
methods: {
  onClickNew() {
    this.data.push(folderName)
  },
```

Now i want to pass the dataUpdate to the child component, where I'm formatting it first, and then I'm filtering it, first by name, then by date, and then by isDeleted or not. And then I'm passing it to the ant design table:

```
<a-table
  v-if="this.item.toString() === '1'"
  :columns="columns"
  :row-key="record => record.guid"
  :data-source="filteredList"
  :pagination="pagination"
  :row-selection="rowSelection"
>
</a-table>
props: [
 'item',
 'searchField',
 'data',
 'addingNewFolder',
],
mounted() {
  this.format_data();
},
computed: {
  filteredList() {
    const dataToBeFiltered = this.item.toString() === '1' ?
         this.allData : this.item === '2' ?
           this.allData.filter(item => {
              return moment().diff(item.lastAccessedDate, 'hours') < 24
           }) : this.item === '3' ?
             this.allData.filter(item => item.isDeleted === true) : [];

    const filter = this.searchField.trim().toUpperCase();
    return filter ? dataToBeFiltered.filter(item =>
    {
      return item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
    }) : dataToBeFiltered;
  }
},
methods: {
  format_data() {
    this.data.map(item => {
      let date = item.lastAccessedDate;
      let formatedDate = date.substr(0, date.indexOf(' '));

      let updatedItem = {
        guid: item.guid,
        isDeleted: item.isDeleted,
        size: (item.sizeBytes / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2),
        name: item.name,
        sharing: item.sharing === 1 ? 'Public' : item.sharing === 2 ? 'Shared' : item.sharing === 3 ? 
           'Private' : '',
        lastAccessedDate: moment(formatedDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
      };
    
      this.allData.push(updatedItem)
    })
  },
},
```

The problem is that whenever I try to add a folder to the array, it won't show it in the table, I don't really know how to listen for the change in the data and then to display it in the table

Comment: If you try console.log the folder on component mount you can see them?

Comment: Yes the data gets pushed in the array, but the problem is that the child component doesn't see the change

Comment: What about changing the prop name `data`  to something else? If I'm correct that should be reserved in vue (because of `data()` )

Comment: at the end of the second file you say `this.allData.push(updatedItem)` but what is `allData`?